# My AWS SES account got suspended since somebody used my SMTP credentials for spamming

Tags: laravel, amazon-ses, laravel-7

I have a Laravel 7 based application that lets people sign up for an event. I have used AWS for hosting the application and AWS SES for sending emails. After a couple of days of setting up this application, AWS suspended my SES service saying that somebody spamming using the sender email account I have used in the Laravel App for sending emails.

When I checked the SES dashboard I was able to see that there were 50000+ emails sent from that email address without my knowledge. I'm using SES for a long time in my other applications and never faced such an issue. This is something new for me. This is my first Laravel App and hence I'm not sure how the spammers got the SMTP credentials from my code. I'm storing SMTP credentials in the .env file and using bitbucket as the repository. It is a private repository only. One mistake I did was I accidentally pushed the .env file of the Application to the bit bucket repository but which is a private repo.

Does anybody have similar experiences with Laravel and SES? Anybody got a hint of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you wanna check if you accidentally push bootstrap/cache/config.php to bitbucket as well

Comment: I checked it but no cache files being pushed. I still don't have clue want went wrong. Btw I have removed the email address and keys in question. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @AromalPillai I am also facing similiar issue with SES though my SMTP credentials were stored in AWS Parameter Store. Did you find any solution or reason for this?

Comment: @NupurThakur Where are you storing your smtp credentials? I later realised that I have accidentally stored a copy in the .env file. I removed it from the .env and it solved the issue.

Comment: @AromalPillai Did you get to know the reason for the same? I mean why storing in .env was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I later realised that I have accidentally stored a copy in the .env file. I removed it from there and it resolved the issue.